# jquery select all rows not containing specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to select all rows in a table that don't have a `td` containing certain text.

I can select the rows with this line:

```
var x = $('td:contains("text"):parent');  //muliple td's in each tr
```

How would I use the `:not` selector to invert the selection?

edit: I don't think the line of code above is really accurate. This is how I originally had the line:

```
var x = $('td:contains("text")).parent();  //muliple td's in each tr
```

When I tried to invert the selection, I get all the rows as they all happen to contain a td not containing the text.

Comment: `$('td:not(:contains("text")):parent');`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1: Select all TR that contains text 'my text' in all TD's**

I wouldn't rely too much on the pseudo. Try something like below using filters, (internally pseudo are going to do the same anyway)

```
$('tr').filter(function () {
   return $(this).find('td').filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().indexOf('myText') == -1;
          }).length;
}); //would return all tr without text 'myText'
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dWuzA/

**Case 2: Select all TR that contains text 'my text' in any TD's**

[@squint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697738/jquery-select-all-rows-not-containing-specific-text/16697808?noredirect=1#comment24034428_16697808) made an excellent point in comment

So incase if you want to select all TR that contains doesn't has a specific text in any of the TD's, then you can inverse the conditions.. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dWuzA/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('tr').filter(function () {
        return !$(this).find('td').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().indexOf('22') != -1;
        }).length;
    }).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: This will return rows that have at least one cell that does not have the text. In other words it excludes rows only when all cells have the text. OP's wording is confusing, but I assume it means to select rows that don't have any cells containing the text.

Comment: Hi Squint - yes, that's right.  I did mention multiple td's in each tr, but should have made it clear that they would all have different values.  When I try to invert the selection I pretty much get all the rows.

Comment: @user1634700 Updated answer with both the versions.

Comment: Thanks Vega - it was case 2 I was looking for.  I simplified it to:    $('tr').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('td:contains("22")').length;
});

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var $x = $('td:not(:contains("text")):parent');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JFEC6/)